# Themes broken after update?

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, 22.04, yaru

After updating, my themes broke. If I use the default orange with light, it gets mixed between dark and light. If I use a different color, it will use the default gtk3 theme on gtk3 apps. If I use the dark, it's much of the same.

How should I fix this?

[Light theme with orange accent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIMF1.png)

[Light theme with different accent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmGlK.png)

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu 22.04 GTK switched to gtk4. A theme, that has no gtk-4.0 folder will not work.

So you either have to switch to a theme that supports GTK4 (gnome-looks has a lot of them) or you have to tweak your theme:

Create a folder named `gtk-4.0` and copy the contents of the gtk3.0 folder. Then you may have to remove some "offending" css commands, (like -gtk-icon-effect or -gtk-radial..). The "offending" calls should be detectable if you open an app in a terminal.

It should be mentioned, that some apps (e.g. gnome-calculator) will not accept a theme just by switching it via `gnome-tweaks`. A workaround would be to start it with a dedicated theme like: `GTK_THEME=YourSelectedTheme gnome-calculator` or add your favorite theme (that has the gtk-4.0 folder) in your `.profile`file at your home directory.